# import cv2 error affected by ROS kinetic cv2 installation

Tags: python, opencv, ros, dji-sdk

I encountered this error when attempting to run a python3 script with the line import cv2.
Seems like it is affected by my ROS kinetic installation

```
    import cv2
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg yes seems like it could. But removing it from the bash file might cause other inconveniences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple workaround.
Add this line to the top of the code

```
import sys 
sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```